# Android manifest merge error

Tags: android, xml, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I am using Unity3D for my project, but am having issues building to Android.

The error I get is this:

> /Volumes/MacBackup/AppsProduction/MyApp/Temp/StagingArea/AndroidManifest-main.xml:24:9-31
>   Error:
>         Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
>         is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>         Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest-main.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.
>
> ```
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
> ```

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker.AndroidPickerActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" android:value="XXXXX" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fbXXXXX" />
    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXXXXXX" android:exported="true" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="18" tools:overrideLibrary="com.onesignal.onesignalsdk"/>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vulkan" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
</manifest>
```

Unity gives me this solution to try, but do not know where to put it:

> tools:replace="android:value

I have searched the internet for a solution on this and a lot comes up with changing something in the build.gradle but do not know where that is in Unity.

Hoping for help in this matter and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You look to have two equal libs with different versions, keep just one, and by reading the message from unity you must add it to the root <manifest

Comment: @Mansa You need to add this line in Android Manifest File above 
uses-permission like: <uses-sdk
        tools:replace="android:value" />